# Docker: invalid character 'U' looking for beginning of value

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, docker-machine

When I run `docker-machine ls`, my DigitalOcean docker droplet can't be reached and an error is displayed.

That same error, `invalid character 'U' looking for beginning of value`, appears when running any other `docker-machine` commands that attempt to contact the docker machine directly.

```
NAME                 DRIVER         STATE     DOCKER        ERRORS
digitalocean-main    digitalocean   Error     Unknown       invalid character 'U' looking for beginning of value
```

Comment: can you paste your docker run command?

Comment: @Adiii I don't think this is related to the `docker` command. The docker ***machine*** can't be accessed, which means no commands will work.

Comment: okay so this is issue and still not working. https://github.com/digitalocean/godo/pull/156

Comment: https://github.com/digitalocean/godo/issues/142

Comment: @Adiii, yes, that's the one! Hopefully the change makes it into the next version of the driver

Comment: did you got the asnwer? from the comment?

Comment: I have found the answer, I am typing it up now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the Digital Ocean API token/key was deleted.

- To fix the error, first generate a new API token on DigitalOcean.
- Then, replace the `"AccessToken"` value with the new token in the file `~/.docker/machine/machines/machine-name/config.json`

Either way, the error message is not obvious. @Adiii [posted a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57916508/docker-invalid-character-u-looking-for-beginning-of-value/57916623#comment102251602_57916508) in the comments to [an issue in the DigitalOcean Go API](https://github.com/digitalocean/godo/pull/156) used by the [Docker machine driver](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/drivers/digitalocean/digitalocean.go#L13) for precisely this problem. Hopefully the fix makes it into the next release.